# Pop for request access to contacts not show ios 9

Tags: ios

I'm fetching contacts from address book but popup not show to ask permission to access contacts. it automatically denied but when i try same code in a demo then it run properly but it ddi not run in my app.
I have read many articles but i did not get any solution. Is i'm missing something in plist or settings.

```
CNContactStore * contactStore = [[CNContactStore alloc]init];

    if ([CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts] == CNAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        [contactStore requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * __nullable error) {

            if (granted==YES)
            {


            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Error");
            }
        }];
    }
```

or second methods

```
 CFErrorRef error = nil;
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);

    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {

    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             NSLog(@"error %@", error);
         }
         else if (granted)
         {

}
         CFRelease(addressBook);
     });

    }
```

Comment: yes but i have done reset device and simulator. many times.

Comment: Printing description of _userInfo:
{
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Access Denied";
    NSLocalizedFailureReason = "This application has not been granted permission to access Contacts.";
}

Comment: i don't add anything into info.plist.

Comment: Any further progress on this?

Comment: Yes have delete my info.plist and create new info.plist then it's working fine.

Comment: @VikashRajput - what was different about your newly created info.plist?

Comment: nothing new. I just delete my plist and create new plist and it start working.

Comment: @VikashRajput Is there any property in your plist which relates to the ContactStore or contacts in general? I am having the same issue - the ```requestAccessForEntityType``` block will not run for me.

Comment: Never mind, for me, it turned out to be that I wasn't initialising the contact store object - so thanks for ```CNContactStore * contactStore = [[CNContactStore alloc]init];``` - very helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

I also had this issue today, and I deleted some keys from Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string></string>
<key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
<dict/>
<key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
<string></string>
```

It works now.  wired case.

Comment: Thank you.. I had to remove `CFBundleDisplayName`.. The others weren't there anyway :) ... Wonder wat causes this

Answer (score 1):

Entering my application's name in the info.plist "Bundle display name" key allowed my app to show a request for access to my contacts.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Cody's answer led me to try this which worked for me.

In your Info.plist, for the key "Bundle display name", make sure it's not an empty string.  This name is used when prompting for the contacts permission.