# Loading Contacts Crashing iOS 10 Swift

Tags: ios, swift, contacts

I am trying to access and load all contacts on iOS 10; however, my app crashes every time the controller loads. I just converted my project from Swift 2 to Swift 2.3 (it was working on Swift 2). I have also added the Privacy Usage for Contacts in my info.plist, but that did not fix the issue. Here is my code:

I found this from a tutorial online to request for access :

```
 func checkAccessStatus(completionHandler: (accessGranted: Bool) -> Void) {
    let authorizationStatus = CNContactStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(CNEntityType.Contacts)

    switch authorizationStatus {
    case .Authorized:
        completionHandler(accessGranted: true)
    case .Denied, .NotDetermined:
        self.accessStore.requestAccessForEntityType(CNEntityType.Contacts, completionHandler: { (access, accessError) -> Void in
            if access {
                completionHandler(accessGranted: access)
            } else {
                print("access denied")
                print(accessError)
            }
        })
    default:
        completionHandler(accessGranted: false)
    }
}
```

I keep getting this error: 
"Optional(Error Domain=CNErrorDomain Code=100 "Access Denied" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Access Denied, NSLocalizedFailureReason=This application has not been granted permission to access Contacts.})"

The code above is a snipper from my controller where the error is happening. I am attempting to request access but it keeps failing. Are there additional steps I need to do to receive access to the contacts? I am not getting a popup box asking for permission when I load the page (even though I added the privacy bit in the info.plist for contacts usage). I have also checked the privacy settings & looked to see if I had disabled the app's access to contacts; however, it is not showing. I appreciate any help, thank you!

Update: I found this question, which seems to be a similar problem (though it is iOS 9) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33142499/pop-for-request-access-to-contacts-not-show-ios-9). How do I delete my info.plist and make a new one?

Comment: At what line do you get the crash? Next time don't make people ask you for very simple details like that! (Why not convert to Swift 3?)

Comment: Sorry about that! I was in a bit of a hurry! I am going to update it to be more specific now, my apologies!

Answer (score 0):

Move `checkAccessStatus` to your Contact Controller and try this method again?